# TSQL converting varchar to int - numeric say 1 and I get a point '.' at the end of the varchar?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, int, numeric, varchar

I am facing a problem with the convertion of a varchar in a numeric value.

I have following SQL Code

```
DECLARE @Test varchar --f.e. '12345'
DECLARE @TestNum int
.......

IF ISNUMERIC(@Test)=1 then
 SELECT @TestNum=@Test
......
```

In debugging mode I can see, that @Test is numeric. But I get an exception:

> cannot convert '12345.' in int.

Where does this '.' come from?

Using cast/convert is the same problem. Also facing this problem when changing from target type int to numeric.

Replace does not find anything, so I am not able to eliminate that point ('.').

Has anyone any suggestions for me?

Comment: Declaring as `DECLARE @Test varchar(100)` give any different result?

Comment: `IsNumeric` will also return 1 for values that can't be converted to int. Use `try_cast` or `try_convert` instead. Also, never declare a varchar without specifying length.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is a terrible function; and that's putting it nicely. It returns both false positives (`ISNUMERIC('.')`) and false negatives (`ISNUMERIC('')`). As @ZoharPeled said, use `TRY_CONVERT`/`TRY_CAST`. They are far better functions and you can be specific on whether you're converting to an integer, decimal, or floating point value.

Comment: `declare @TestNum Int, @Test VarChar(10) = '12345'; set @TestNum = @Test; select @Test, @TestNum;` executes without errors. Without an explicit length for the string the values are `'1'` and `1` due to truncation. What else does your code do? Do you have different data? And, to pile on, [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/).

Comment: Select try_convert(money,'12345.')   ...  You can wrap it in a convert(int, ... ) if you like

Comment: These are just a few examples, but notice that **all** of the values here can be converted to at least one of numerical data types, but very few of them all of them. `ISNUMERIC` on the other hand, only gives you what is effectively a "yes" or "no" answer and it is never correct for all of them. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=404a8862394b9d4ccb1764312b96561c).

Comment: and another example that @Larnu missed - `ISNUMERIC('1d3')` will return 1...

Comment: @ZoharPeled: which, bizarre as it is, is correct, for certain values of "correct" -- `CONVERT(FLOAT, '1d3')` is 1000, even though this format is *not* accepted as a literal. Oh, the endless fun you can have in SQL Server with `ISNUMERIC` and conversions...

Comment: Clearly `'1d3'` is a number... It's the result of when you roll a 3 sided die; so it's any number between (and including) 1-3. A "number" like `3d6" is any number between 3 and 18, with higher chances of the middle numbers being selected. Those *are* numbers right... Just probable numbers. >_<

Comment: SQL Server would be much cooler if it supported die rolls, but unfortunately this is just someone's idea of being accommodating enough to support [Fortran double precision literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#Examples_and_other_notations). This is undoubtedly also what inspired accepting things like `'-'`, converting the empty string to `0` (or `1900-01-01` if you want a `DATETIME`) and other conventions that are bewildering and unhelpful in most production setups but semi-useful for importing flat text from your 1976 mainframe if all you have is `bcp` and SQL Server.

Comment: Supply a full example demonstrating the error you mentioned. You are asking about a mysterious dot being appended but have given no code reproducing this